# Combine video and audio TS segments coming from HLS stream

Tags: streaming, transcoding, mpeg

Apple HLS streams MPEG-2 TS files containing video and audio data in packetized elementary stream format. These segments (`.ts` files) can be joined in order to build final video.

Recent version of HLS can now produce segments with video data only in TS files, and audio data only in another TS files. This is used to serve multilanguages video.

Regardless of HLS itself, how can I process to remux TS files containing video data, and audio data, in one TS file? Joining TS files together doesn't work; I get data from first TS file combined with the same type of data from next TS files (only video or audio).

Comment: I don't know enough to give an actual solution, but some reading seems to indicate that FFMPEG may be able to deal with this.

Comment: I just checked and yes, you are right. FFmpeg handles HLS with multiple audio tracks. I will take a look at source now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [tsMuxer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR) to add the audio stream from one .ts file into the .ts file containing the video or vice versa. This is called muxing and doesn't affect the quality of the audio or video in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [`m3u8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) file? If so, I assume you can just do

```
ffmpeg -i indexfile.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.ts
```

You could also convert it directly into the mp4 container:

```
ffmpeg -i indexfile.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Comment: This does not work when the indexfile.m3u8 has a separate url for audio and a seperate url for video_01.m3u8

Comment: @chovy: Can you show me that file? I think it should possibly work with option `-map` and maybe a second option `-i` which takes the same inputfile (in your case `video_01.m3u8`).

Comment: it works if i do `ffmpeg -i <audio-stream> -i <video-stream> -async 1 -c copy test.m3u8`